# how to print barcode in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing, barcode-printing

i have an asp.net website, and i want to print some barcodes in c#. i use "IDAutomationHC39M"  font as bellow:

```
public static void PrintSmallBarcode(HtmlGenericControl divBarCode, string barCode)
    {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
        using (Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(75, 18))
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitMap))
            {
                Font oFont = new Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 7);
                PointF point = new PointF(0, 0);
                SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                SolidBrush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                graphics.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, 0, 0, bitMap.Width, bitMap.Height);
                graphics.DrawString(barCode, oFont, blackBrush, point);
            }
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();

                Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
                imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
                imgBarCode.CssClass = "cssbarcode";
            }
        }
        div.Controls.Add(imgBarCode);
}
```

it works, but the quality of barcode is sow low, and my barcode reader device failed to read it. i can not increase the size of image, and of course i see a lot of good barcodes smaller than my size. i replace "IDAutomationHC39M" font with "free3of9.ttf", but this font just draw the number and no barcode line!.
how can i get a better barcode?

Answer (score 0):

This is a long-standing problem with barcode fonts; they are enormous and scan horribly because printers try to anti-alias the bars.

Use images, not fonts, to draw barcodes. There are many packages available, for example [Barcode Rendering Framework](http://barcoderender.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use other datas to change the size of the barcode.I used keepautomation [barcode generator for asp.net](http://www.keepautomation.com/products/net_barcode_aspnet/) to create barcode images in Visual C# ASP.NET project.After my settings,i can preview the size of the barcode.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.